# spring-boot Actuator together with Spring Security and Form Basic Auth

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have added "spring-boot-starter-actuator" dependency to my spring-boot project.

The project already has form based security.

The root context for the application is "/".

I have added the actuator at the context root "/actuators" by adding to application.yaml:

management:
  context-path: /actuators

The non-sensitive actuators are working, such as "health".

When I try to access the sensitive actuators, the popup appears for username/password. The authentication takes place, but then I see "403" Access is Denied.

Here is the configuration for Web security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
private AuthenticationLookupService authenticationLookupService;
private AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;
private UrlSuccessAuthenticationHandler successHandler;

@Autowired
public void setAuthenticationLookupService(AuthenticationLookupService authenticationLookupService) {
    this.authenticationLookupService = authenticationLookupService;
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    this.authenticationManagerBuilder = auth;
}

@Autowired
public void setSuccessHandler(UrlSuccessAuthenticationHandler successHandler) {
    this.successHandler = successHandler;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index.html", "/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/index.html").successHandler(successHandler)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();

    http.csrf().disable(); // todo: fix later
}

@PostConstruct
public void process() throws Exception {
    this.authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(this.authenticationLookupService).passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Add below values in application.properties or application.yml and then when popup asks for username and password provide this credentials

```
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=secret
```

If you are providing your values check if that user has `ADMIN` role, because actuator needs ADMIN role user to access sensitive end points.

**Update**
If you are using spring-boot 1.5.*+ then user should have `ACTUATOR` role

Comment: I think only the part about ADMIN role is actually the relevant here.

Comment: @Nikem if user wants the actuator values to be accessed only with certain credentials then we can restrict using the approach I told in my answer